# Check if an element is present in a array #minizinc

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, minizinc

I'd like to check which is the number between 1 to 5 that not occurs in the array group and put this number (or numbers) in an other array.

```
g=2;

set of int: GROUPS = 1..g; 

groups = [{1, 3}, {2,5}];

p=5;

set of int: PEOPLE = 1..p;
```

I tried in this way but it doesn't work.

```
int: peopleInGroup= (g*g);
set of int: INGROUP = 1..peopleInGroup;
array [INGROUP] of var int: inGroup;  

int: peopleNotGroup= c-(g*g);
set of int: NOTGROUP = 1..peopleNotGroup;
array [NOTGROUP] of var int: notGroup;     


constraint forall(i in groups,person in i) (if sum(j in PEOPLE-1)  (i==person then inGroup[i]=person else notGroup[i]=person  endif));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case `groups` is a **literal** *-as in your question-*, then you can use set and list **comprehensions** *-described at page 22 of [this tutorial](http://www.minizinc.org/downloads/doc-latest/minizinc-tute.pdf)-* to achieve your goal.

**e.g.**

```
set of int: DOM = 1..5;
set of int: population = DOM;
array[1..2] of set of DOM: groups = [{1, 3}, {2, 5}];


% array initialization

array [int] of var DOM: in_array =
               [i | i in DOM where exists(g in groups) (i in g)];
array [int] of var DOM: out_array =
               [i | i in DOM where not exists(g in groups) (i in g)];

% set initialization

var set of DOM: in_set =
               {i | i in DOM where exists(g in groups) (i in g)};
var set of DOM: out_set =
               {i | i in DOM where not exists(g in groups) (i in g)};


solve satisfy;

output [
    "in_set=", show(in_set), "\n",
    "out_set=", show(out_set), "\n",
    "in_array=", show(in_array), "\n",
    "out_array=", show(out_array), "\n"
];
```

***note:*** `var` can be dropped from definition of all variables, here I use it only because `flatzinc` would otherwise not print their content on standard output.

The output is:

```
~$ mzn2fzn example.mzn ; flatzinc example.fzn
in_array = array1d(1..4, [1, 2, 3, 5]);
in_set = {1, 2, 3, 5};
out_array = array1d(1..1, [4]);
out_set = {4};
----------
```

---

Here is the generated intermediate `flatzinc` model:

```
array [1..2] of set of int: groups = [{1, 3}, {2, 5}];
array [1..4] of var 1..5: in_array :: output_array([1..4]) = [1, 2, 3, 5];
var set of 1..5: in_set :: output_var = {1, 2, 3, 5};
array [1..1] of var 4..4: out_array :: output_array([1..1]) = [4];
var set of 1..5: out_set :: output_var = 4..4;
solve satisfy;
```